# Using displayed cases

Tags: math-mode

I only installed LaTeX just over 3 weeks ago and I've written about 20 pages of Maths coursework.  I have a bit of an issue with arrays - I am trying to use something like `dcases` to show a piecewise function.  My function involves fractions and they come out too small but I can't seem to follow other people's answers to this problem because I am not familiar with the packages etc.  Please could you look at my document set-up, as below, and suggest what I'm doing wrong?  When I use  the `amsmath` package, things disappear off the ends of pages and everything moves!

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}       % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
%\usepackage{geometry}                      % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                         % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                       % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}          % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
%\usepackage{graphicx}              % Use pdf, png, jpg, or eps with pdflatex; use eps in DVI mode
                                % TeX will automatically convert eps --> pdf in pdflatex        
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm,bindingoffset=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in,include foot]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Chloe Jones A2460906}
\chead{TMA MST326 03}
\rhead{\thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\title{TMA MST326 03}
%\author{Chloe Jones A2460906}
%\date{March 2015}                          % Activate to display a given date or no date
\begin{document}
%\maketitle


H= \begin{array}{lr}
 \\
0 & : \textrm{n even,}\ \  n\neq2\\
\\
 \frac{5\pi + 2n\pi +  5\pi - 2n\pi  }{ \pi ^2 \left({4 - n^2  }\right)}    & :  \textrm{n odd}
 \end{array}
\right.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your code into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? There is nothing wrong with what you've posted. We need to see a working example in order to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Please, may you give us a image with the formula that you would like write.

Comment: Sorry I have limited time for a coursework deadline - I've changed my values here - and I would find it too difficult to post an image but I would be grateful if you could help with my code please. I was just trying to input a large brace for a piecewise function.  The function is zero for odd n and the value of the function is a fraction involving n when n is odd. Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 13):

The `cases` environment, provided by the `amsmath` package, is ready-made for your math expression. Note that the `cases` environment renders each line in text-style math mode (aka inline math mode). If you don't need to conserve space, consider using a `dcases` environment instead: It displays the fractional term in display-style math mode and also increases the space between rows.

Either way, the entire expression, starting with `H=`, has to be in math mode. This can be achieved by placing it in a `\[ ... \]` group.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads 'amsmath' package, provides 'dcases' env.
\begin{document}
Using a \texttt{cases} environment:
\[
H= \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n$ even, $n\neq2$}\\
\frac{5\pi + 2n\pi +  5\pi - 2n\pi}{\pi^2 (4 - n^2)} & \text{if $n$ odd}
 \end{cases}
\]

\bigskip
Using a \texttt{dcases} environment:
\[
H= \begin{dcases}
0 & \text{if $n$ even, $n\neq2$}\\
\frac{5\pi + 2n\pi +  5\pi - 2n\pi}{\pi^2 (4 - n^2)} & \text{if $n$ odd}
 \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- As @daleif has observed in a comment, the `dcases*` environment may also be of interest. It differs from the `dcases` environment in that the material *after* the `&` character is automatically placed in text mode, obviating the need for the `\text{...}` wrappers. Using a `dcases*` environment, one could write the solution as follows:

```
\[
H= \begin{dcases*}
0 & if $n$ even, $n\neq2$\\
\frac{5\pi + 2n\pi +  5\pi - 2n\pi}{\pi^2 (4 - n^2)} & if $n$ odd
\end{dcases*}
\]
```

Comment: Even funnier: `dcases*` then you don't need `\text` in the second column (hardly any is using that version)

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for this note. I've provided an addendum to illustrate its use for the example at hand.

Comment: Your wording is a little off, shouldn't it be "after the `&` char is..."

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for pointing out the issue with the wording in the addendum; I've replaced "environment" with "character".

Comment: But shouldn't it still say "after the `&` character" , that $ char does not make sense?

Comment: @daleif - Two typos, back to back. :-(